# How to create self-executing anonymous function in Object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

in my object

```
let obj = {
  name:["Harry","Scren","Docis","Altab"],
  age:[32,44,22,55]
}
```

I need to write down a self executing anonymous function in object that, when i call any member of the object it will execute that self executing anonymous function and it will check whether the length of both array (name and age) are equal or not, If not equal then throw an error .....I need to have something like

```
let obj = {
  name:["Harry","Scren","Docis","Altab"],
  age:[32,44,22,55],

  (function(){
    if(name.length != age.length){
      throw new Error('both name and age 's length are not equal')
     }
    }()) // But this is not possible to create in object I have just showed down what I wanted to create
}
```

How to create something like that in javascript object ??

Comment: Just put the IIFE outside the object literal and pass obj.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the real answer is [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#defining_getters_and_setters) or a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Why would you want that, when you have written what the arrays are yourself? Can you give a dynamic example where this would make sense? Also, you have a syntax issue with string literals.

Comment: The one problem is the data. If name and age are related, use a map-like structure as proposed in the answer. You can also create a validation function to check the data and throw an error when it is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that's not possible...
But let me ask a question: why you have an obj containing two arrays? Hasn't more sense having an array of the obj which each element of the array contains one name and one age? I'll show you

```js
const people = [
    { name: "Pearson 1", age: 20 },
    { name: "Pearson 2", age: 20 },
    { name: "Pearson 3", age: 20 },
    { name: "Pearson 4", age: 20 },
]
```

So you do not have to check the length since every obj has its own name and age field.